# Show/Hide panel of parent control

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, forms, designer

I have a base class inheriting from UserControl on which there is a panel. I made a property that allows me to show/hide the panel.

```
public partial class BaseControl : UserControl
{
    // ...

    private Panel panTitle; // this is actually declared in the designer file..

    public BaseControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // hide the panel by default
        IsTitlePanelVisible = false;
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsTitlePanelVisible
    {
        get { return panTitle.Visible; }
        set { panTitle.Visible = value; }
    }
}
```

Now if I open some other control inheriting from BaseControl in the designer, the panel is visible!
After I change the IsTitlePanelVisible property to true and back to false in the property window, it disappears.

I also set the Visible property of the panel itself to false in the designer of BaseControl, but it still shows up.

Has anyone some advice on how to get the panel to not show up when opening a derived control in the designer?

Edit: To make things clearer, there's the following addition:
I already have a quite large number of derived controls and I don't want to change all of them.
If I open a derived control and manually set the value to false, everything works fine, but I can't understand why it wouldn't work since the value is set to false in the base control's constructor..

Comment: Why is "panTitle" declared in the class and not in the designer.cs file?

Comment: I only added it here to show that it is of type Panel, it actually is declared in the designer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to invoke the base constructor

```
class DerivedControl : BaseControl
{
     public DerivedControl()
        : base()
    {

    }
}

class BaseControl : UserControl
{
     public BaseControl ()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // makes the panel visible by default
        IsTitlePanelVisible = false // makes the panel hidden explicity
    }
}
```

Also from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.DEFAULTVALUEATTRIBUTE%29;k%28DEFAULTVALUE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) :

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically
>   initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value
>   in your code.

Comment: That changed nothing. Also, the base() call is inserted by the compiler by default if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick test application to see if I could duplicate your problem. The only thing that I did differently was to add the panel in the designer and set its visibility to false. It worked correctly doing that. It looks like you are creating the panTitle Panel manually. Where/When are  you adding it to your control, your best bet would be to add the Panel like I stated above.

---

**Edit:**

In reading  your question a little closer, it seems like you are not wanting the Panel to showup when you are looking at the DerivedUserControl's Design Tab. What I have posted will not change that, I am not sure if that behavior can be changed. It will not be visible when you drop it on a Form though and in that way acts like expected.

---

Here is a quick working example.

**Form1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DerivedUserControl dv = new DerivedUserControl();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Controls.Add(dv);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dv.IsTitlePanelVisible)
                dv.IsTitlePanelVisible = false;
            else
                dv.IsTitlePanelVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Base UserControl**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class BaseControl : UserControl
    {
        public BaseControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsTitlePanelVisible
        {
            get { return panTitle.Visible; }
            set { panTitle.Visible = value; }
        } 

    }
}
```

**BaseControl.Designer.cs InitializeComponent**

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.panTitle = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // panTitle
    // 
    this.panTitle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
    this.panTitle.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    this.panTitle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.panTitle.Name = "panTitle";
    this.panTitle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 147);
    this.panTitle.TabIndex = 0;
    this.panTitle.Visible = false;
    // 
    // BaseControl
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.Controls.Add(this.panTitle);
    this.Name = "BaseControl";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

**Derived UserControl**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class DerivedUserControl : BaseControl
    {
        public DerivedUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "In reading your question a little closer, it seems like you are not wanting the Panel to showup when you are looking at the DerivedUserControl's Design Tab."  That is exactly the problem I've been trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `panTitle.Visible` to false by default?

the ComponentModel `DefaultValue` attribute is only used for the designer to determine whether the property in the propertyGrid should be shown as bold (dirty) and whether its value should be generated to the `InitializeComponent` method of *derived* classes of the `BaseControl`

Comment: This only makes it hidden at runtime. As for now, the only possibility I see is to set the property to false in the designer code of the derived control, even though it should be false already..